# Bootstrap css class values

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add custom class in html file with bootstrap, but I cant find the source or complete list of style values in CSS file for specific class..
What I want is to modify form group input text class so it can be like input type=number in regular html form and I can't find the values for colors and padding and the rest.

Comment: Why don't you override them? Insert your custom style AFTER the bootstrap css.

Comment: I dont want to override them, i need to implement same values for borders,shadow,height and such so that my input=number can be same as input=text in design...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the best solution is add your css after bootstrap and change what you want

```
<head>
..
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- your css file -->
<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
...
</head>
```

Comment: I need css first...the problem is in getting the entire property sheet for specific class..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's better you override them in your file.
If you have any trouble making any of them "stick" use `!important`

Eg: `padding-top:10px !important;`

Comment: I dont want to override them, i need to implement same values for borders,shadow,height and such so that my input=number can be same as input=text in design. basicly i'm making a class with similar properties...

Answer (score 0):

I fpund most of the values and edited button css inline with like this

input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" step = "0.1" style="padding:6px 12px; border:1px solid #ccc; border-radius:4px; height:34px; font-size: 14px;box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);"

this is the best solution for now..i havent been able to reproduce values for transition effects but this is close enough...